# why NodaTime do not support some countries?

Tags: c#, nodatime

i used "NodaTime.dll, v1.2.0.0" in my site to calculate time zone i use this code to retrieve ZonedId:

```
 var tempInfo = (from location in TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
                where  location.CountryCode.Equals(countryCode, 
                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    select new { location.ZoneId, location.CountryName })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

it works fine but when i want to use it for "Ascension Island" by Country code :"AC" Or "UK" for United Kingdom, it returns null.

i want to know this library do not support this or I'm on the wrong way?

Comment: The time-zone database was never meant to support automated mapping.  It has enough entries to allow a user to pick one nearby from a list.  "Nearby" doesn't mean same country, and same country doesn't mean nearby.

Comment: Also, the two-letter ISO code for United Kingdom is GB, not UK.

Comment: In particular, the USA spans eight time zones.  So there doesn't exist any way to do the mapping based only on country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just a matter of the data which is in CLDR and TZDB. (As it happens, I'm in the middle of updating to the CLDR v25 mapping data.)

The UK is present using its ISO-3166 code of "GB". The ISO-3166 code for Ascension Island is SH-AC, and SH *is* present, mapping to "Atlantic/St_Helena". (I'm not even sure whether St Helena normally counts as a country in its own right; countries get very confusing.)